Remote desktop a Hyper-V VM without public IP
I am running Windows Server 2022. I created a virtual machine using Hyper-V. How can I connect to it via RDP using the host's IP address?
I tried changing the Remote desktop port to a different port than the host's port and connect but it didn't work.

You can set up a Port Forwarding/NAT Mapping on the host to forward traffic for a specific port to the Hyper-V virtual network. With something like this:
Add-NetNatStaticMapping -NatName NATNetwork -Protocol TCP -ExternalIPAddress 0.0.0.0/24 -ExternalPort 53389 -InternalIPAddress 172.16.10.100 -InternalPort 3389
See more details in this article: Create NAT Rules for the Hyper-V NAT Virtual Switch
